# Is it possible to have multiple hovers on one object/area?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So right now I have CSS with `:hover` on some elements and all is good, but now some text/html content is wanted on the hover.

What it is now:

```
<div id="first">
<a class="hover_thing"></a>
</div>
```

Where `#first` is just some regular container and the anchor  has some `background-image` property set on `.hover_thing:hover`.

What I want to do:

```
<div id="first">
<a class="hover_thing"></a>
<a class="second_hover_thing"></a>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="first" class="another_hover_thing">
<a class="hover_thing"></a>
</div>
```

Where `.hover_thing` works as before, but hovering over it also causes a secondary hover change because of the second anchor or `div#first`.

I've also tried doing this with jQuery by using tooltip plugins and whatnot (specifically jQuery Tooltip from flowplayer.org, simpletip and qTip), but those also break the hover from the first set of code.

Is this unpossible or am I just doing this wrong? Also at this point, I'm open to more than just CSS answers, so any Javascript solutions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'd still use CSS.

Just put the `second_hover_thing` in your HTML, and give it `display:none` in CSS.

Then give it `display:inline` when its parent `#first` gets `:hover`.

CSS

```
#first .second_hover_thing {
    display:none;
}
#first:hover .second_hover_thing {
    display:inline;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="first">
    <a class="hover_thing">hover thing</a>
    <a class="second_hover_thing">second hover thing</a>
</div>
```

Or if you wanted it to activate specifically when hovering over `hover_thing`, you could try this:

```
.second_hover_thing {
    display:none;
}
.hover_thing:hover + .second_hover_thing {
    display:inline;
}
```

...although I'm not sure of the cross browser support for the `+` selector. You'll have to test.

[From quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t12), it looks like there are some IE issues with `+`, so be sure to test.